# Start Node script on button click in React/Express app & kill the same script on another button click?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, spawn

I've written a live-streaming chat bot script in Node and have built a simple React/Express app to go along with it as a set of basic user controls - one button to start the script and another to kill it.

The bot script works as a continuous listener for specific chat commands so there's no natural end to the script that would trigger a process exit event for the Express server file to listen for.

My first thought was to configure app endpoints for each button in my main server file, one to handle the process start, the other to kill it, but every angle I've approached this from (spawning processes, ps-node) so far has produced nothing but errors.

On the Express side, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

Yes this is absolutely possible. Your idea of configuring two endpoint was the right starting point.

I played a little with different solutions and found out the following works atleast for me. In my solution I setup two endpoints `/start` and `/kill/:pid` for controlling the spawning and killing. In the frontend I then use fetch to trigger these endpoint.

### Code

##### server.js

###### /start

Using spawn to start process. "another.js" is for testing and also never ends to simulate your example.
You would replace "node" and [__dirname + \another.js] with your
way of starting the bot. Finally send pid to frontend.

###### /kill/:pid

Simply receive the pid via `req.params` and spawn the `taskkill` command for windows to kill the process with given pid. On linux you would use `kill`. So make sure to replace it if needed

```
const express = require('express');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); // this is here for my testing purpose as I did not wanted to setup a full react app
});

app.get("/start", (req, res) => {
  let pid = spawn(`node`, [__dirname + "\\another.js"]);
  pid.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  res.send({ pid: pid.pid });
});

app.get("/kill/:pid", (req, res) => {
  let pid = req.params.pid;
  spawn(`taskkill`, [`/F /PID ${pid}`]);
  res.send("Done");
});

app.listen(80, () => {});
```

##### frontend (index.html)

As said I used plain HTML but the fetch functionality just needs to be build into your react app. Make sure to save the pid somewhere in your state so you can later kill the bot script.

```
  <button id="spawn">Spawn</button>
  <button id="kill">Kill</button>
  <script>
    let id;
    document.querySelector("#spawn").addEventListener("click", async () => {
      let response = await fetch("/start");
      let { pid } = await response.json();
      id = pid;
      console.log(pid)
    });
    document.querySelector("#kill").addEventListener("click", async () => {
      let response = await fetch(`/kill/${id}`);
      let text = await response.text();
      console.log(text);
    });
  </script>
```

### Resources

- [How to use nodejs spawn](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/)

Comment: What did you use to test this with in another.js in your example?  

I recreated your example using setInterval to console log some text from another.js and was able to properly spawn the process but it isn't terminating properly on the kill click.

Comment: Update: I was able to get your example working by converting the taskkill spawn line from a template string to a concatenated one.  Thank you!  I knew this was somehow possible.

Comment: Glad, we worked something out.